# How to created image from Widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to create an image file of any particular widget and save it in an external storage directory?

Ex. to create an image of `RandomWords` widget.

```
class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => new RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return Text(wordPair.asPascalCase);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you mean how to make a screenshot of a given widget I suggest you read this article on Medium: [Take a ‘Screenshot’ Of a Certain Widget in Flutter](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/take-a-screenshot-of-a-certain-widget-in-flutter-ad263edc4e55)

Especially the `takeScreenshot()` method might be of your interest:

```
takeScreenShot() async {
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  double pixelRatio = originalSize / MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pixelRatio);
  ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  setState(() {
    _image2 = Image.memory(pngBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
  });
  final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File imgFile = new File('$directory/screenshot.png');
  imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('Saved to ${directory}'),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Ok',
      onPressed: () {
        // Some code
      },
    ),
  );

  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

Comment: what is 'previewContainer'?

Comment: That is just a variable holding the `Key` of the target Widget.   
I suggest watching the  [excellent tutorial about Keys on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)  
 . Also I highly suggest reading the article on medium I posted in my answer.